# Как получить услуги для записи с yndex карт?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть необходимость в api для получения услуг у организаций подключенных к yandex т.к. там 10+ сервисов выдают нужные данные в едином формате.
Когда на яндекс картах выбираешь организацию есть кнопка *Записаться онлайн*, после нажатия открывается выбор услуг и специалиста, и при нажатии на *Услуги* улетает запрос по пути "https://yandex.ru/maps/api/booking/getServices" который в результате дает такой массив:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цель получить этот массив, в документации yandex api, я не нашел возможности использовать этот endpoint и пока нет грамотных идей как это реализовать

Какие есть способы получения этих данных? возможно я упустил этот метод в API?

Comment: Такие детали организаций — это уже не API Яндекс Карт, это Яндекс Бизнес, из которого карты грузят себе инфу. А Бизнес по API полный доступ к данным не предоставляет. Минимальный набор как раз в API Поиска по организациям и есть. А всё, что вы решите взять парсингом или ещё как, нарушает пользовательское соглашение Яндекса, за что они вполне вправе на любой ваш проект блокировку поставить со своей стороны.

Comment: По этому я и обратился на форум с целью найти способ реализовать это верным методом и ищу идеи, парсить я и не планировал

Comment: Ну вот потому суть ситуации целиком и я обрисовал, как мог. Легальных возможностей сейчас Яндекс не предоставляет. Им тоже нужны пользователи в их сервисах, потому какие-то возможности и данные они на своих сервисах оставляют эксклюзивом.